# Is it possible to use a .NET desktop application as the receiver for Google Cloud Messaging notifications?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-messaging

If I would like to get notifications from a server through GCM both on my device (Android / iOS) and my desktop .NET application, I know I can get notifications to Chrome.

Is this even possible? Or should I consider other notification services?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (after looking at documentation) that google only provide API's to android, IOS and Chrome unfortunately. You may be better off using a different service.

Comment: Any suggestions for other services which meets this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible - for used GCM you need Google service inside client side. Only android device with google service.